# Plot a single point on number line in interval notation

Tags: notation

For example, I want to plot the solution set $\{3\}\cup (2, \infty$). How do I represent 3 as a single point?

Comment: Do you want $\{3\}$ denoted as interval? Then $\{3\}=[3,3]$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct notation for a set with only the point $3$ in it is $\{3\}$. If you really want to use interval notation, you could also denote this as $[3,3]$.

Notice that your solution set is just $(2, \infty)$ though, since $3$ is already in the set $(2, \infty)$.

Comment: What I meant was how I can plot an individual point on the number line. Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: Usually you just draw a dot (i.e. a point) at the point 3 on your number line.

Answer (score 1):

If you needed to represent $\{2\}\cup(4,\infty)$, then you could use a filled-in dot for individual points, so you might draw something like the following:
[image: 2 and (4,infinity)]

As Alex G. mentioned, since $3$ is in $(2,\infty)$, $\{3\}\cup(2,\infty)=(2,\infty)$ so you wouldn't have to do this for the case you mentioned in your original question.